# Run custom action at the end of Entity Framework update-database execution

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working on a project that uses Entity Framework code-first and SQL Server.  We're increasing our usage of stored procedures, and rather than having each sproc create/alter/drop/etc command in ef migration files, I'm thinking that I'd like to store one copy of each proc in source, and just install the latest versions of each after the update-database action has completed.  I think that doing so will allow me to keep one copy of each sproc/view/function/etc in source outside of the migrations, and make the migration files cleaner.

Does this make sense to do?  Are there best practice recommendations for managing storage and deployment of stored procedures when using EF code-first?

Comment: I should also ask what mechanism I might use to run a custom action to deploy non-schema objects as part of, and at the end of the update-database command?

Answer (score 0):

Since Visual Studio 2013 you have the option of creating database projects, this allows you to have control of the structure and code of the database and take it to a repository, compare and version it

[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-create-a-new-database-project?view=sql-server-ver15) y [Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijDcHGxyqE4)